# How to determine how the admin created a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I use **"publish_post"** hook to intercept post creating

```
function detect_post_created( $post_id, $post ) {
    
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'detect_post_created', 10, 2 );
```

Admin can create post in **Admin UI** and in **Wordpress app (iOS/Android)** via REST API.

How can I detect - Admin UI or Wordpress app was used to create current post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to check some information from the server variables to determine how the user created it. I can't tell you exactly what you'll need because it depends on your system and the mobile app, but inspect the server variables:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>';
die;
```

You might be able to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to determine if it was the mobile app. You could also check the URLs in some of the other values, or possibly `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.